# Gmail limits number of filters and forwarding addresses by 30 or less

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create 30 forwarding addresses.
2. Create 30 filters, one for each address.
3. Export them.
4. Delete non-essential information in XML file, keep only tags with expressions and actions.
5. Delete all filters in Gmail UI.
6. Import them with Gmail UI.
7. Repeat #5,#6 multiple times.

At some point Gmail will not import all 30 filters.

I believe you will be able to reproduce with 10 addresses and multiple re-imports.

Does anybody know what is that Google internal Gmail threshold that I hit and what are specific parameters of such threshold? And also why does Google put such limit at all? Is this a bug? How to make Google fix that bug?

Comment: Contact google support and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know what is that Google internal Gmail threshold that I hit and what are specific parameters of such threshold?

AFAIK in order to prevent abuses, only few Googlers know "internal thresholds".

> And also why does Google put such limit at all?

To prevent abuses.

> Is this a bug?

This doesn't look like a bug to me.

> How to make Google fix that bug?

Google has several official channels for users to send feedback:

Send your feedback directly to Google from the Gmail web UI

1. Go to gmail.com and sign in
2. Click on the settings button and then on Send Feedback
3. Fill up the form

Share your feedback with other users through the [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail) where  other few users could scalate the post to Googlers.

Bear in mind that non-critical issues could take a while to be fixed.